# Copying part of 2D array into another 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write C code that takes a block of a 2D array and copies it into another 2D array by using the `memcpy` function. In the particular code I have included, I have tried to copy the last 3 columns of the 2x4 array `matrix` into the 2x3 array `mat_copy`.

```
double matrix[2][4] = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};
double mat_copy[2][3];
double sz = sizeof(mat_copy)/2;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    memcpy(&mat_copy[i][1], &matrix[i][1], sz);
}
```

I'm getting the output: `[0, 1, 2; 3, 5, 6]` instead of `[1, 2, 3; 5, 6, 7]`. How does the `memcpy` function choose which addresses to copy once you give the initial pointer in memory? I know my error has to do with addressing the 2D arrays, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Do you know how multidimensional arrays are laid out in the memory?

Comment: You are not going to copy columns.  You are going to copy rows.

Comment: Make `sz` a `size_t` rather instead of a `double`.

Comment: The sizeof the last 3 columns is the same as the size of 3x any one element of `mat_copy`.  `size_t sz = 3 * sizeof mat_copy[0][0];` or in this case, the size of 1 row of `size_t sz = sizeof mat_copy[0];`

Answer (score 2):

You're starting from `1` in your destination instead of `0`, so you're copying past the end of the row.

Change

```
memcpy(&mat_copy[i][1], &matrix[i][1], sz);
```

to

```
memcpy(&mat_copy[i][0], &matrix[i][1], sz);
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy the last 3 columns, you must pass the offset of columns 0 as destination.  You can further simplify the code this way:

```
double matrix[2][4] = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}};
double mat_copy[2][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    memcpy(mat_copy[i], &matrix[i][1], sizeof(mat_copy[i]));
}
```